# opencv's morphologyEx function throws error when I try to use it on an binary image with added noise

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

I used the following code to :

1. create a black images (of dtype - UINT8 and FLOAT64)
2. add white text
3. create white noises  (of dtype - UINT8 and INT32)
4. add combinations of image and noise
5. apply morphological operation (opening) to the final images

**Problem** I get an error when I apply morphologyEx to UINT8 image with added INT32 noise, while the function does not throw an error for FLOAT64 image with added UINT8 noise.

***error:*** OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\imgproc\src\morph.cpp:891: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Unsupported data type (=4) in function 'cv::getMorphologyRowFilter'

```
img1 = np.zeros((300,600),np.uint8)
cv2.putText(img1, 'ABCD', org=(100,200), fontFace=cv2.FONT_ITALIC, fontScale=5, color=(255,255,255), thickness=25)

img2 = np.zeros((300,600))
cv2.putText(img2, 'ABCD', org=(100,200), fontFace=cv2.FONT_ITALIC, fontScale=5, color=(255,255,255), thickness=25)


noise1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(300,600), dtype=np.uint8) 
noise2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(300,600)) 

noise1_img1 = img1+(noise1*255) 
noise2_img2 = img2+(noise2*255) 
noise1_img2 = img2+(noise1*255) 
noise2_img1 = img1+(noise2*255) 

opening1 = cv2.morphologyEx(noise1_img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
opening2 = cv2.morphologyEx(noise2_img2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
opening3 = cv2.morphologyEx(noise1_img2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
# Error
# opening4 = cv2.morphologyEx(noise2_img1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
```

###### Error when I try to run opening 4 :

[image]

Comment: see [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f): `The depth should be one of CV_8U, CV_16U, CV_16S, CV_32F or CV_64F` and your `noise2_img1` is `CV_32S`.

Comment: Can you add the error message in your question (as a text, not as an image) ? It will help to reference your question for people encountering the same problem.

Comment: Yup makes sense. The dtype of src (noise2_img1) is int32 which is CV_32S. 
(Also added the error statement as text to question)